# What is a compact way to generate the list of $n^m$ composite functions, given a list of n functions and a composition depth of m?

Tags: list-manipulation, programming

**Introduction.**

An image says more than a thousand words.

[image]

The functions sym4ref (pmm) and sym4rot (p4) create symmetries of a geometric object in the 2D Euclidean Space. ( pmm, p4 refer to the list of 17 Wallpaper Groups, see: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_planar_symmetry_groups#Wallpaper_groups ).

In the List **ind** I collected the 4 possible compositions of the two functions :

```
ind := {
  Composition[sym4ref, sym4ref],
  Composition[sym4ref, sym4rot],
  Composition[sym4rot, sym4ref],
  Composition[sym4rot, sym4rot]
}
```

such that I can simply iterate over them :

```
Table[ind[[k]][dpoly] // toGL // gr, {k, 1, 4}]
```

( The function **toGL** is an intermediary function which translates 'dpoly' in custom, tailor made, geometry code, to standard Mathematica code, **gr** is short for the standard Mathematica function Graphics )

So far, the practical application side of the problem.

**Problem**

The question is about generating an indexed list of composite functions like:

```
ind := {
  Composition[sym4ref, sym4ref],
  Composition[sym4ref, sym4rot],
  Composition[sym4rot, sym4ref],
  Composition[sym4rot, sym4rot]
}
```

Let's focus and make this a bit more abstract, but look at an example first. Let the list of functions of be ${f_1, f_2}$ and the requested composition length 3, in which case we would expect as result:

```
ind := {
  Composition[f1, f1, f1],
  Composition[f1, f1, f2],
  Composition[f1, f2, f1],
  Composition[f1, f2, f2],
  Composition[f2, f1, f1],
  Composition[f2, f1, f2],
  Composition[f2, f2, f1],
  Composition[f2, f2, f2]
}
```

**Question**

Now, assume a list of n functions, i.e. $f_1, f_2, ... f_n$, and a requested composition length of $m$.

What is the most ( read: a very ) compact way to code the generation of the list of $n^m$ composite functions, where the list of $n$ functions is given, as well as the requested composition depth $m$ ?

**Reason**

The reason for asking this question, and the emphasis on it, is **compact functional code**. I am always surprised, 'in awe', have much respect for the skill of writing compact functional code, a skill which I have not, and probably never have.

Or, going back to the introductory example:

```
Table[ind[[k]][dpoly] // toGL // gr, {k, 1, 4}]
```

I would like to do this as:

```
Table[g[funclist, m][[k]][dpoly] // toGL // gr, {k, 1, Length[g[funclist, m]]}]
```

where g is the function asked for.

**Epilog**

[image]

Comment: Something like this? `Composition @@@ Tuples[Array[f, n], m]`?

Comment: m, I understand, where is the input list of  functions?

Comment: Indexed as `{f[1],f[2],...}`

Comment: So f is ind as in the example above ? Which is the request.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want  to receive a `List` of functions and an `Integer`, then

```
cmp[fl_List, m_Integer] := Composition @@@ Tuples[fl, m]

cmp[{f1, f2}, 3]
(* {f1@*f1@*f1, f1@*f1@*f2, f1@*f2@*f1, f1@*f2@*f2, f2@*f1@*f1, f2@*f1@*f2, f2@*f2@*f1, f2@*f2@*f2} *)
```

Or, after the comment by @CarlWoll,

```
cmp[fl_List, m_Integer] := Tuples[Composition @@ fl, m]
```

And since you did say *most compact,*

```
cmp[{f_, g___}, m_Integer] := Tuples[f@*g, m]
```

But at the time you are defining your functions, you could *name* them already with an indexed  expression, and instead of `{f1, f2, f3, f4, f5}` you could have `{f[1], f[2], f[3], f[4], f[5]}`. In that case,

```
Composition @@@ Tuples[Array[f, n], m]
```

Comment: @MichaelE2 I think Tuples does support such syntactic sugar, e.g., you could use `Tuples[Composition[f1,f2], 3]`

Comment: It works as expected, thank you very much.